# Why do some usernames in comments have a backtick background?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've noticed that only some usernames have the grey backtick background, for example only the last comment's username is highlighted (but not the other comments),

[image]

And in this shot only Tanner's username is highlighted,

[image]

What's causing this to happen? Is this a bug?

Comment: That's not the backtick background... it's decidedly not gray on the main site (where the same thing happens, in case you haven't noticed).

Comment: Respond to this comment, Sam - to see how it works (as per my answer)

Comment: @Oded Oh I see now. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comments by the OP are highlighted.

That's all there is to it.